# How to use environment variables in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables

I want to load properties from external file present under my home directory. I set a environment variable using the file as follows

```
export ENV_HOME=/home/usr/environment.properties
```

I want to use the properties present in environemnt.properties files in spring-boot application. I don't want to include this in packed jar

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use @PropertySource("${ENV_HOME}") in controller will override the properties from external file.